# Remove Getdeb from Ubuntu System

Tags: apt

I tried deleting it from `/etc/apt/sources` and `/etc/apt/sources.d`, but whenever I run `apt-get install` for any package , it gives the following output in the end

```
Setting up getdeb-repository (0.1-1~getdeb1) ...
--2016-05-16 17:16:03--  http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key
```

And the "getdeb" entries magically come back in `/etc/apt/sources.d`. Is there any fix to remove "getdeb" completely from my system?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Can you please make the full log for me?

Comment: Setting up getdeb-repository (0.1-1~getdeb1) ...
--2016-05-16 17:16:03--  http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key
Resolving archive.getdeb.net (archive.getdeb.net)... 144.76.200.19
Connecting to archive.getdeb.net (archive.getdeb.net)|144.76.200.19|:80...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Answer (score 2):

System Settings ->  Software & Updates -> Other Software, uncheck `archive.getdeb.net` box.
Worked fine on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Also worked for Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove getdeb-repository
```

Also delete refs to getdeb in `/etc/apt/sources.lst`

Answer (score 0):

Your connection might be unstable or slow, so you must go to Update Manager, then to Settings, then to Servers, and click on Select Best Server button, once the best server is chosen, try removing it again.